# Jump through search results in UIWebView with Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, search, uiwebview

I have set up a search in uiwebview with javascript that works great, but I want to be able to  jump to the next found word in the search results. I have succeeded in geting the view to scroll to the first instance by using this code:

```
if (uiWebview_SearchResultCount == 1)
{
   var desiredHeight = span.offsetTop - 140;
   window.scrollTo(0,desiredHeight);
}
```

How can I get this searchresultcount to update to the next found result(say 2, 3, 4, 5, ect...) when user presses button in app?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do basically the same thing with this javascript in the webview:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var max = 100;

function goToNext() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/hl/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#hl",""));
        (newh > max-1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#hl" + String(newh-1); 
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "hl1";        
    }
}

</script>
```

Then sending this JavaScript call with my IBAction like this:

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    [animalDesciption stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"goToNext()"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a native button in your app such as a UIButton?  In that case, you can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to execute some JavaScript in your UIWebView. You could do something like this as the handler for your button:

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender {
    NSString * js = @"uiWebview_SearchResultCount++;";
    [yourUIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
}
```

Comment: This is very much like what I'm wanting to do, but I can't seem to get it working... Any further advice would be appreciated. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's not working without more details.  Do you have your button action set up correctly?  Could you possibly post some more of your code?

Comment: @JakeStoeffler I copied your code and it doesn't work and i am sure button action is correct because i wrote some nslog in it, can you please help me? i dont know javascript but i can post here javascript code which i am using

Comment: @yucelbayram I'd be glad to help, but let's do that in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33397/ios-uiwebview-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

call this function with the appropriate row?

```
function scrollToDesiredHeight(row) {
   var desiredHeight = span.offsetTop - 140;
   window.scrollTo(0,row * desiredHeight);
}
```

Does this work for you?